# Intercom icon does not appear after login (Intercom-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intercom

I am trying to use 'intercom-rails' in my app. I followed the installation from here : https://github.com/intercom/intercom-rails. Now Im able to see the chat icon and chat.

However, if I login, the chat icon disappears. It does not appear even after logging out.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means something is causing the Intercom JavaScript code to crash or not report the needed information to be activated.

First, check your browser JavaScript console for errors. If there is something wrong when rendering the Intercom widget, it will show up there.

Then, I suggest that you look into your HTML code using the "View Source" function on your browser and take a look at how the Intercom Javascript code is being rendered when the chat icon does not appear.

You should see something like this:

[image]